# arc4random() efficiency breaks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, cocoa, arc4random

Kind of an oddball question here but should be pretty basic for someone familiar with the implementation of `arc4random`.

Does it use an appropriate integer based on the number you use after the modulo? Example it would use `int` for a number |255| or a `long int` for a number |2147483647| or does it just use something completely different implementation?

I don't really need a huge number but I wouldn't mind using as large of pool as I can without a hit to performance. So that's my reason for asking about this.

Comment: If you're asking whether `arc4random() % 5;` and `arc4random() % 65536;` are running different code, the answer is that the function doesn't have that kind of knowledge of its calling context.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yep, that was the main part of my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arc4random() and arc4random_uniform(UInt32) both return UInt32, so the size of the number you'll get is limited by that.  I think that's actually something over 2 billion.

Comment: I checked and the maximum value for UInt32 is 4,294,967,295

Comment: That's why you should probably use arc4random_uniform().  The input to this is the range of integers you want.  e.g. arc4random_uniform(10) would give you integer random numbers between 0 and 9 inclusive.

Comment: You could also divide the return from arc4random() (maybe after casting it to float or double) by some number to reduce the range.